# Search a keyword and Print the first pattern between 2 same patterns from a file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I got a log file where I need to print the first line if a keyword is present in between the patterns.

For example:

```
LEVEL: X
abc 
123 
def rty 
LEVEL: A
abc
123
LEVEL: Z
abc
def 345 rty
ocp
```

Search is between pattern "LEVEL" for keyword  "def".

Expected Output:

```
LEVEL: X
LEVEL: Z
```

Looking use awk or sed, as the log file more than 10000 lines.

I have tried something like

```
awk '/LEVEL:/{flag=1}/LEVEL:/{print;flag=0}flag' file
```

But I am not sure how to search for the keyword "def" in the list and print only the matching first line of it.

Update:

```
awk '/LEVEL:/{flag=1}/def/||/LEVEL:/{print;flag=0}' file
```

But the output is as such

```
LEVEL: X
def rty
LEVEL: A
LEVEL: Z
def 345 rty
```

To be more clear, I am tying to search between 2 consecutive patterns "LEVEL:" the keyword "def".

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Currently, there is nothing in your sample input that would meet the requirements. (no `"def"` between any `"LEVEL: .."` tags.)

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts but your Logic of getting expected output is not clear, please do mention your Logic more clearly in your Question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I have updated the post. I hope it is clearer now?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: There is def between first and second "LEVEL:". But for the last pattern "LEVEL: Z" there is no corresponding "LEVEL:" pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
$1=="LEVEL:" {
  lvl=$0
  next
}
lvl && index($0,"def") {
  print lvl
  lvl=""
}
' file
```

This saves the "LEVEL" line so that it can be printed if "def" is found.

Comment: That's a nice one!

Answer (score 1):

In GNU awk using [`RT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#index-RT-variable-3):

```
$ gawk -v RS="LEVEL[^\n]+" '/def/{print p}{p=RT}' file
```

Output:

```
LEVEL: X
LEVEL: Z
```

Another:

```
$ awk '/^LEVEL/ {
    if(f)
        print p
    f=""
    p=$0
    next
}
/def/ {
    f=1
}
END {
    if(f)
        print p
}' file
```

Comment: The gwak work to the most part.. there was "LEVEL.x" also in my log which added few extra entries.. Thank you for your help..

Comment: Yeah, that's why the sample data should always portray the real data in the best possible way. When the sample data is `123`, `abc` or `qweqwe`, you kind of know that there is always the extra something to mess up the solution, so usually the solution is kind of a general guideline on how to start solving the problem—for me, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^LEVEL/h;/def/{x;p}' file
```

This is a filtering operation so turn off implicit printing `-n`.

Make a copy of each line beginning `LEVEL`.

If a line contains `def` print the last copy.